# Inserting ooxml content at binding causes issues with styling for last paragraph

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, openxml, office-addins

When using the `setDataAsync()` method to target a binding in the Word document and populate it with ooxml content, the styling is not being applied to the final paragraph of the xml content being inserted. For reference, the Word document is entirely blank at the point of binding and insertion.

The `document.xml` portion of the content control looks like so:

```
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:pa="https://precisely.cloud/kisoji-report-generator" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" >
        <w:body>
          <w:sdt>
            <w:sdtPr>
              <w:alias w:val="myContentControl"/>
              <w:id w:val="00"/>
              <w15:appearance w15:val="hidden"/>k
              <w:showingPlcHdr/>
            </w:sdtPr>
            <w:sdtContent>
              <w:p>
                <w:r>
                  <w:t>Some placeholder text</w:t>
                </w:r>
              </w:p>
            </w:sdtContent>
          </w:sdt>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
```

and the `document.xml` portion of the content being inserted looks like so:

```
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:pa="https://precisely.cloud/kisoji-report-generator">
        <w:body>
          <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
              <w:pStyle w:val="SectionHeading" />
              <w:jc w:val="center" />
              <w:spacing w:after="180" />
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
              <w:t xml:space="preserve">First paragraph text</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
          <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
              <w:pStyle w:val="SectionHeading" />
              <w:jc w:val="center" />
              <w:spacing w:after="180" />
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
              <w:t xml:space="preserve">Second paragraph text</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
```

The relevant `styles.xml` portion of the content being inserted:

```
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
        <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:default="1" w:styleId="Normal">
          <w:name w:val="Normal" />
          <w:qFormat />
        </w:style>
        <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:customStyle="1" w:styleId="SectionParagraph">
          <w:name w:val="SectionParagraph" />
          <w:basedOn w:val="Normal" />
          <w:qFormat />
          <w:pPr>
            <w:spacing w:after="120" />
          </w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
            <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1" />
            <w:lang w:val="en-US" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:style>
        <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:customStyle="1" w:styleId="SectionHeading">
          <w:name w:val="SectionHeading" />
          <w:basedOn w:val="SectionParagraph" />
          <w:qFormat />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:style>
      </w:styles>
    </pkg:xmlData>
```

When the above content is inserted to the Word document at the binding described in the content control, the styling is only applied to the first paragraph and omitted for the second. By inserting an additional paragraph (e.g. `<w:p/>`) at the end of the xml content, however, the first two paragraphs are styled as expected. For some reason, the styling is being dropped for the last paragraph of inserted content. I've looked through the OOXML documentation and Microsoft's own add-in tutorial, but nowhere does it seem to explain why this might be happening.

Why would inserting content at a binding cause issues with styling in this way?

Comment: What happens if there is only 1 paragraph in the document? Does it get styled? I'm suspecting that it doesn't ... which might lead to at least a potential reason. Attached to the last paragraph are many crucial bits for the WindWord software.

Comment: @RichMichaels indeed, if there is only 1 paragraph, no styling is applied. Could you elaborate on why you suspect this might be?

Comment: As I said, attached to the last paragraph of a document, the Word software attaches many document formatting controls. Section controls and their corresponding items like margin settings, page orientation, header and footer settings, etc. You might call it the Word's link to the other content layers of the document.

Comment: I should also add that some of these same linkage "bits" reside in the last paragraph of each Section, in multi-section documents. With that said though, I don't know "Why" your XML code is failing to set the style on that last paragraph, but it must have something to do with this very special paragraph and a conflict that is occurring. Another interesting test might be to create a multi-section document and see if your code has a problem in each Section ... or is it just the last paragraph in the document.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and suggestion. What is also interesting is that the same issue I encountered can be replicated in the sample [repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-AddPopulateBindings) referenced in Microsoft's `Create Better Add-ins` documentation. In `SampleContent2.xml`, if you remove the second paragraph (the diagram) in the `document.xml` portion, leaving only the first paragraph, and insert the content at a specific binding, the sole remaining paragraph will no longer be styled. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: My thought ... they probably knew it didn't work and that's why they stuck in the second paragraph with a diagram. Who cares about changing the paragraph style on a diagram, really? That might have been the author's logic. I'm curious if you tried the multiple section document test I mentioned and the results you got.

Comment: A possible issue is a sequence you are changing styles. Do style "based on" settings get fouled up due to the sequences of your changes? Another thought ... have you tried running the routine twice back to back? Does that change the results? Have you tried adding something special just for the last paragraph? Performing a specific change just for that specific paragraph. Here is a link that might help you design a workaround. [How to create or add a style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-and-add-a-paragraph-style-to-a-word-processing-document)